# PlayStore warning application due to SslErrorHandler

Tags: cordova, ionic3, android-security, cordova-android, sslerrorhandler

We develop an application with Cordova and Ionic 3, and after updating a new version of our app into the Play Store we got the following warning.

Here follows a screenshot of the warning:

[image]

We use as environment:

```
cordova-android: 7.1.4
cordova-cli: 8.0.0
ionic: 3.20.0
```

Only related code I found was in the file **SystemWebViewClient.java** under cordova engine, which we can't really alter and have never altered, since it's under the generated folder *platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/*.

And this is the code that can be found:

```
 /**
 * Notify the host application that an SSL error occurred while loading a resource.
 * The host application must call either handler.cancel() or handler.proceed().
 * Note that the decision may be retained for use in response to future SSL errors.
 * The default behavior is to cancel the load.
 *
 * @param view          The WebView that is initiating the callback.
 * @param handler       An SslErrorHandler object that will handle the user's response.
 * @param error         The SSL error object.
 */
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

    final String packageName = parentEngine.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
    final PackageManager pm = parentEngine.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();

    ApplicationInfo appInfo;
    try {
        appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
            // debug = true
            handler.proceed();
            return;
        } else {
            // debug = false
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // When it doubt, lock it out!
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @AdrianKrebs Yes, we were able to track down the class **a.cf** to a third party library that we use, and so they sent us a newer version with the fix.
We discovered it by reverse engineering the apk file, and tracked it to the third party library, I would recommend doing the same to pinpoint the issue, at least. Something else you could do is write a script to modify the appropriate file for a workaround in this issue.